# Manipulate a matrix based on another matrix

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have a variable `est` which is `20x1` double, something like this:

```
12
15
68
85
0
25
3
...
```

and variable `k` which is also `20x1` double consisting of `0`, `1`, or `2`, something like this:

```
1
2
0
1
0
0
2
...
```

I would like to change `est` so that if a `k(i)` is not `0` then `est(i)` should be removed, where `i=1:20`. Could anyone help?

Comment: What is your definition of "blank"?  Do you want to **remove** `est(i,1)` from the matrix?

Comment: Yes, I do want to remove `est(i,1)` from the matrix.

Comment: What you are asking for is not possible.  MATLAB does not support uneven matrices where the number of columns per row don't need to match over all rows.  The only way you can perhaps do this is by a cell array.  If you want to entertain the cell array option, I can write an answer, but in terms of a numeric matrix, removing entries per row, thus rendering the matrix to be [irregular or ragged](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irregular_matrix) is not supported in MATLAB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a solution using a `For` loop statement. Let me know if this correspond to what you are looking to do:

```
idxList = [];
for ii = 1:size(est,1)
    if k(ii,1) == 0
        idxList = [idxList ii];
    end
end
est(idxList) = [];
```

The code makes a list of index for all zero that it finds in variable `k`. After that, it removes all values from the variable `est` that corresponds to the value in the index list `idxList`.

Comment: This is not a particularly idiomatic way to perform this operation. You can replace that entire loop with the statement `idxList = k(:,1) == 0`.

Comment: Good point. You can indeed replace the loop with that one liner. I've put the loop so that the OP can modify it to his needs. I expect he needs to do that on more than 1 column.

Comment: I have only one column so that one line will work fine. Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 0):

By "blank" do you mean 0?

```
est(k(:,1)~=0, 1) = 0;
```

What is this code doing?

`k(:,1)~=0` returns a 20 x 1 logical array that is true at rows where the first column of `k` is non-zero. The code then addresses these rows in `est` along column 1 and sets the values to zero.

Comment: I don't think `blank = 0` here.... else the OP could have just said 0 if you take a look at the context of his problem statement (i.e. *if a `k(i,1)` is not 0*).... then again, I have no idea.

Comment: You can't set a single value to "blank" in a matrix though.

Comment: That's right, which is what the OP wants now... (see comment above).

Comment: I guess I could try `est(k(:,1)~=0, 1) = NaN; est(isnan(est))=[];`

Comment: `est(isnan(est))=[];` will convert `est` into a column vector with the NaN elements removed. I'm not sure that's what you want.

Comment: rlbond is correct.  This will reshape your matrix into a single column vector with all of the `NaN` elements removed.  If you want to implement ragged matrices, cell arrays is an option.  You could also implement these via dynamic structures, but I have a feeling that you want this via numerical matrices, and that is unfortunately not possible.